# Ember naming / capitalization convention

Tags: ember.js

The way I understand it, we are encouraged to name Ember instances lowercase:

```
App.mailtruck = Em.Object.create({...});
```

...and classes uppercase:

```
App.Mailtruck = Em.Object.extend({...});
```

Would it be correct to say that instances of Ember.Namespace are the sole exception to this rule? Also, are there any cases besides Namespaces where this convention is strictly important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, namespaces are the exception to this rule. As you said, it's `lowerCase` instances and `UpperCase` classes. Also `Mixins` should be named `UpperCase`, so it's: `App.LoggerMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({});` (Thanks @**sly7_7** for the catch)

Further details can be read in the great blog post by the Emberist: http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html.

Comment: Reading this article: http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object
I realize that Mixins are another exception of "capitalized" instances. Right ?

Comment: Now the answer seems complete, so +1 ;). Seriously, glad to learn more every day I work with ember and read about it.